# MySQL query: use each result/row to regex and count another table

Tags: mysql, regex, count

Not sure if this is possible. With two tables, one is country codes:

e.g.

```
id | code | country

1    .us    United States
2    .ru    Russia
```

And so on (about 200+ rows)

The other is URLs:

```
http//:example.gov.us
http://example.gov.ru/index.php
http://xyz.gov.us/test.html
```

And so on.

I don't know what URLs will come in, so I would have to grab each country code and somehow query the URLs for any matches against the country codes and count how many there are for each.

e.g (?)

```
gov.[country code]
```

Ideally, I would like the output to be grouped by country name and counted, something like, using the above URLs as an example, it might result in:

```
country | total

United States | 2
Russia  | 1
```

Like I said, not sure if this can be done in MySQL with regex, substrings etc. Would love to know if it can be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a query like this:

```
SELECT
  c.country,
  COUNT(*)
FROM
  countries c INNER JOIN URLS u
  ON SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(url, 'http://', -1), '/', 1)
     LIKE CONCAT('%', c.code)
GROUP BY
  c.country
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6e6d1/1).

Using `SUBSTRING_INDEX(url, 'http://', -1)` you can get the whole string after the http://

```
http://example.gov.ru/index.php  --->   example.gov.ru/index.php
```

then using `SUBSTRING_INDEX(..., '/', 1)` on this string you can get the part of the string before the first / or the whole string if there's no /

```
example.gov.ru/index.php         --->   example.gov.ru
```

you can then check if `example.gov.ru LIKE '%.ru'`

Comment: minor problem perhaps if they have example.gov.fr.ru

Answer (score 0):

```
select country, count(*) total
from country_codes c
join urls on urls.url RLIKE CONCAT("^http://[^/]+\\.gov\\.", c.code, "($|/)")
group by county
```